# Unable to Inherit HR.Employee in OpenERP

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Please show me where my mistake is. I need to add a new field called `kanganyname` (manager name). But it's giving me an error. I followed the developer guide and done this modification:

Here is my view.xml

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="namelist_dailyupdate">
    <field name="name">checkroll.daily.update.form</field>
    <field name="model">checkroll.daily.update</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form" />
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="daily_update">
            <field name="kanganyname" />
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_inherit_ex">
    <field name="name">checkroll.daily.update.form</field>
    <field name="model">checkroll.daily.update</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
</record>
```

Here is my model class.

```
class dailyupdate(osv.osv):
    _name = "checkroll.daily.update"
    _inherit = "hr.employee"
    _description = "This table is for daily update"
    _columns = {
        'kanganyname': fields.char('Kangany Name', size=256, required=True)
    }

dailyupdate()
```

Here is my error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/sql_db.py", line 226, in execute
>          res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
>      IntegrityError: null value in column "res_model" violates not-null constraint
>      
>      2013-03-18 04:10:16,830 4709 ERROR OpenERP_DB openerp.tools.convert: Parse error in /home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/addons/checkroll/checkroll_view.xml:179: 
>      
>                  checkroll.daily.update.form
>                  checkroll.daily.update
>                  form
>                  form
>              
>      Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 847, in parse
>          self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n)
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 814, in _tag_record
>          id = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')._update(cr, self.uid, rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode, context=rec_context )
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 964, in _update
>          res_id = model_obj.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4434, in create
>          cr.execute('insert into "'+self._table+'" (id'+upd0+") values ("+str(id_new)+upd1+')', tuple(upd2))
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/sql_db.py", line 161, in wrapper
>          return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/sql_db.py", line 226, in execute
>          res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
>      IntegrityError: null value in column "res_model" violates not-null constraint
>      
>      2013-03-18 04:10:16,835 4709 ERROR OpenERP_DB openerp.netsvc: null value in column "res_model" violates not-null constraint
>      Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/netsvc.py", line 293, in dispatch_rpc
>          result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 425, in dispatch
>          return fn(*params)
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 436, in exp_authenticate
>          res_users = pooler.get_pool(db).get('res.users')
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/pooler.py", line 49, in get_pool
>          return get_db_and_pool(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)[1]
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/pooler.py", line 33, in get_db_and_pool
>          registry = RegistryManager.get(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 192, in get
>          update_module)
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 218, in new
>          openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 344, in load_modules
>          processed = load_marked_modules(cr, graph, states_to_load, force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 259, in load_marked_modules
>          loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 190, in load_module_graph
>          load_update_xml(module_name, idref, mode)
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 74, in 
>          load_update_xml = lambda *args: _load_data(cr, *args, kind='update_xml')
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 127, in _load_data
>          tools.convert_xml_import(cr, module_name, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 954, in convert_xml_import
>          obj.parse(doc.getroot())
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 847, in parse
>          self._tags[rec.tag](self.cr, rec, n)
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/tools/convert.py", line 814, in _tag_record
>          id = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')._update(cr, self.uid, rec_model, self.module, res, rec_id or False, not self.isnoupdate(data_node), noupdate=self.isnoupdate(data_node), mode=self.mode, context=rec_context )
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 964, in _update
>          res_id = model_obj.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 4434, in create
>          cr.execute('insert into "'+self._table+'" (id'+upd0+") values ("+str(id_new)+upd1+')', tuple(upd2))
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/sql_db.py", line 161, in wrapper
>          return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
>        File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/sql_db.py", line 226, in execute
>          res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
>      IntegrityError: null value in column "res_model" violates not-null constraint
>      
>      2013-03-18 04:10:16,847 4709 INFO OpenERP_DB werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Mar/2013 04:10:16] "POST /web/session/authenticate HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xml code is totally wrong of inheritance.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="namelist_dailyupdate">
    <field name="name">checkroll.daily.update.form</field>
    <field name="model">checkroll.daily.update</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form" />
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="daily_update">
            <field name="kanganyname" />
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

In this your code you not specify where you want  to add new field, you can define your code like this

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="namelist_dailyupdate">
    <field name="name">checkroll.daily.update.form</field>
    <field name="model">checkroll.daily.update</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form" />
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="daily_update">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='name']" position="after">
                <field name="kanganyname" />
           </xpath>
        </form>
   </field>
</record>
```

or

checkroll.daily.update.form
    checkroll.daily.update
    
    form

need to define position your you want to add this field either using xpath or field tag

hope this help

Comment: thanks dear friend..issue sorted now
need to know what is the differ between model & res_model in view.xml

Comment: model and res_model refer same thing object, model is used in view for which we make view and res_model is the name of the object on which the action operates.